# PHP - count my quantity item in session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, shopping-cart

How to count the `item-qty` and current code :-

```
$q = $_POST['item-qty'];
$i = count($q);
$k = 0;

while ($k < $i) {
  $select = 'SELECT * FROM location';
  $query = $db->rq($select);
  $price = $db->fetch($query);

  if ($_POST['item-qty'][$k] < 3) {

      $get = $price['normal_price'];
      $price = $get * $_POST['item-qty'][$k];

      $_SESSION['order'][$_POST['item-id'][$k]] = array(
      "item-id" => $_POST['item-id'][$k],
      "item-qty" => $_POST['item-qty'][$k],
      "item-name" => $_POST['item-name'][$k],
      "item-price" => $price,
       );

  } else {

      $get = $price['member_price'];
      $price = $get * $_POST['item-qty'][$k];

      $_SESSION['order'][$_POST['item-id'][$k]] = array(
      "item-id" => $_POST['item-id'][$k],
      "item-qty" => $_POST['item-qty'][$k],
      "item-name" => $_POST['item-name'][$k],
      "item-price" => $price,
      );
  }
}
```

here the array output

```
Array
(
[order] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [item-id] => 1
                [item-qty] => 1
                [item-name] => Adidas
                [item-price] => 100
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [item-id] => 2
                [item-qty] => 1
                [item-name] => Nike
                [item-price] => 150
            )

    )

)
```

**Question :**

1. How to implement other code if `item-qty` (in all array)  is greater than or equal to 3  will use `$price['member_price']`

let me know :)

Comment: Is there a question? Please clarify what you want to ask.

Comment: Lots of code... Are we supposed to interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you meant the total item-qty of everything?

```
$qty_sum = 0
 foreach($_SESSION['order'] as $order){
     $qty_sum += $order['item-qty'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks GSto!. long question but simple answer